# AWS Device Farm testcases getting failed

Tags: appium-android, aws-device-farm

While running a test cases on AWS Device farm for Samsung Galaxy Note 10,I am getting following error.
P.S: This issue is not because of module.

```
Failed to start Appium server: uncaughtException: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
date=Fri Dec 11 2020 09:09:29 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time), pid=8265, uid=1001, gid=1001, cwd=/usr/local/avm/versions/1.4.16/node_modules/appium, execPath=/usr/bin/node, version=v10.14.0, argv=[/usr/bin/node, /usr/local/bin/appium, --pre-launch, --log-timestamp, --log-no-colors, --use-keystore, --app, /tmp/scratchHgV3fC.scratch/share-cDnEwS.scratch/app-lHmzCQ.apk, --udid, R58M78B6WRN, --address, 127.0.0.1, --port, 4723, --log-level, debug, --platform-name, Android, --tmp, /tmp/scratchHgV3fC.scratch/appium-CqtB4x, --device-name, R58M78B6WRN, --platform-version, 9, --app-pkg, com.audetemi.trackhelp, --app-activity, com.audetemi.trackhelp.ui.activities.SplashActivity, --chromedriver-executable, /opt/chromedriver/linux/65/chromedriver], rss=89526272, heapTotal=73527296, heapUsed=45065896, external=848015, loadavg=[0.4404296875, 0.4755859375, 0.431640625], uptime=6914, trace=[column=15, file=internal/modules/cjs/loader.js, function=Function.Module._resolveFilename, line=580, method=Module._resolveFilename, native=false, column=25, file=internal/modules/cjs/loader.js, function=Function.Module._load, line=506, method=Module._load, native=false, column=17, file=internal/modules/cjs/loader.js, function=Module.require, line=636, method=require, native=false, column=18, file=internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js, function=require, line=20, method=null, native=false, column=31, file=evalmachine.<anonymous>, function=null, line=44, method=null, native=false, column=1, file=/usr/local/avm/versions/1.4.16/node_modules/appium/node_modules/md5calculator/node_modules/unzip/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js, function=, line=11, method=null, native=false, column=30, file=internal/modules/cjs/loader.js, function=Module._compile, line=688, method=_compile, native=false, column=10,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test code is using Appium server version `1.4.16`, and this older version is no longer supported by AWS Device Farm. The minimum required Appium version on AWS Device Farm is `1.9.1`, and using the [custom test environment mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html) feature, you can use much more recent versions like 1.16.0.

To change your Appium version, standard mode users would change their version through the API's test parameter options (test -> parameters -> appium_version) in the [ScheduleRun](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_ScheduleRun.html) API (if using the CLI/SDK). Custom environment users would modify the beginning lines of the `install` phase of their **test spec** file (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html) to use a different version of appium node.

When scheduling a run from the AWS Device Farm console, there will be **test spec** examples for changing your Appium version using `avm`. I recommend taking a look at that sample file for an idea of how to use / configure the custom test environment mode.

If you are still having issues, you can typically get more specific help on the [AWS Device Farm Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193&start=0) or through the support email: `aws-devicefarm-support@amazon.com`